# application closes when call crystal report

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

I have created `wpf` application in VS 2012 with sap crystal report CR13, it works well in developer PC but when I install it on client PC first it throws error:

> "An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
> runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are
> insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed
> correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports
> redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the
> Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to
> http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information."

For that I installed CR Runtime. after that, the error goes but when I call show report method application, it does not respond and ends.

I'm spending a lot of time for that but nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes:

Cr Runtime need `32bit` OS application even you run it in 64bit.

Comment: did you install the 32bit runtime?

Comment: i got solution for that just get correct version of CR runtime